# Unable to use firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[There is a method provided by firestore to increment a numeric value.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value)

But I was not able to use the function because it is undefined.

I tried updating firebase in npm, tried reinstalling firebase. I currently have the 5.10.1 version of firebase.

```
import firebase from "../base";
...
someHandler = () => {
  someRef.update({
      count: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[The problem is that the FieldValue is not accessible through the app instance.](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1776#issuecomment-450763811)

So I solved my problem by importing directly from "firebase" instead of my local file which exports an initialized firebase instance.

Comment: Hi, Could you tell em how you did this?