# How can I increment values in map fields?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function for updating data in firestore

```
  setLocalStorage = name => () => {
    ...

    this.database.collection(this.cookie.get('section')).doc(this.cookie.get('id')).update({
      ['daily.' + name]: this.database.FieldValue.increment(1),
      ['monthly.' + name]: this.database.FieldValue.increment(1),
      ['yearly.' + name]: this.database.FieldValue.increment(1)
    })
  }
```

[image]

I want to increment my values in fields which are an object maps but this method isnt working. How can I do it differently?

Comment: "this method isn't working" isn't enough detail.  Please edit the question to describe in more detail what this code is actually doing that's different than what you expect.  Also it will help if you remove all variables and replace with contants - we can't see the value of `name` and `this.cookie.get('id'))`, so we don't know if those values are correct.

Comment: okay, I actually found a solution by myself by getting values from firestore, incrementing them in another function, adding to object and then updating values to firestore from this object.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question then, or delete it if you no longer need help.

Comment: If you found a solution, can you please post it as an answer, so anybody reading this post can benefit from it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I found a solution (i dont know if its ok but it works). First of all I create new object with proper keys, next I get values from firestore, increment them and ascribe to before created object keys and next I update values in firestore with before ascribed incremented values.

```
    let incrementObj = {
      daily: 0,
      monthly: 0,
      yearly: 0,
    };
    await this.database
      .collection(this.cookie.get("section"))
      .doc(this.cookie.get("id"))
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        let dailyValue = snapshot.data().daily[name] + 1;
        let monthlyValue = snapshot.data().monthly[name] + 1;
        let yearlyValue = snapshot.data().yearly[name] + 1;
        incrementObj.daily = dailyValue;
        incrementObj.monthly = monthlyValue;
        incrementObj.yearly = yearlyValue;
      });

    await this.database
      .collection(this.cookie.get("section"))
      .doc(this.cookie.get("id"))
      .update({
        ["daily." + name]: incrementObj.daily,
        ["monthly." + name]: incrementObj.monthly,
        ["yearly." + name]: incrementObj.yearly,
      });
```

Comment: Thanks! Please note that you can do this as a single step using the Firestore built-in method _fieldValue.increment()_  using _set()_ or _update()_ methods as mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue). From your code above, I can see a possible issue in the way you were importing your database, see for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55897154/unable-to-use-firebase-firestore-fieldvalue-increment